convolution of the fundamental solution with the homogeneous solution
I have a question about the convolution of the fundamental solution with the homogeneous  solution. Namely if the 2 are convoluble then the homogeneous  solution is necessarily zero?
Let $U$ and $E$ be the homogeneous  and fundamental solutions for the differential operator $L$
Meaning that $LE=δ_0$ and $LU=0$
Now assume that $U$ and $E$ are convoluble so that $U*E$ makes sense.
Appling $L$ to $U*E$ we get
$L(U*E)=LU*E=U*LE$ by  the basic property of convolution
$LU*E=0*E=0$ and $U*LE=U*δ_0=U$ because the Dirac delta is the neutral element for convolution
So $U=0$

Here is a not at all rigorous reasoning : $0E = 0L^{-1}(\delta_0) = L^{-1}(0)\delta_0 = U\delta_0 = U$.

@Abezhiko so this means that my calculations are correct ? And valid for all L ?

I must admit I'm not knowledgeable about this stuff to answer you with certainty. A lot of oddities occur when distributions are involved. I suspect that the homogeneous solution might not be a valid test function (cf. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution#Application_to_the_example).

You need to provide more details. What is $L$? What is the domain of the functions (or distributions)? What are your assumptions on $U$ and $E$? In general, they are not unique.

@Deane $L$ is any differential operator with constant coefficients, the order of differentiation can be as large as you want but finite. The domain of the functions (distributions) needs to be $R^n$ to be able to use convolutions.

And the function space is?

@Deane If the function (distribution) is convoluble the space of functions should be irrelevant since the only property used are those of convolution. If you want to consider the space of distributions over $R^n$.

You should write a full rigorous statement of what you have proved.
